# How to implement thread counted singleton with constructor and destructor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, thread-safety

I have multiple threads that construct a parametrized object and call start and stop on it. The issue is, that the underlying service for each parameter should be only started on the first start, and only stopped on the last stop, once. I tried the following:

```
# /usr/bin/env python3
import multiprocessing.pool
import random
import threading
import time
import uuid


def log(args):
    print(f"{threading.get_ident()}: {args}")


class Myobj:
    lock = threading.Lock()
    count = 0

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name

    def log(self, args):
        log(f"{self.name}: {args}")

    def start(self):
        with self.lock:
            self.count += 1
            if self.count == 1:
                self.value = uuid.uuid1()
                self.log(f"starting {self.value}")
            self.log(f"ref up {self.count}")

    def stop(self):
        with self.lock:
            self.count -= 1
            if self.count == 0:
                self.log(f"stopping {self.value}")
            self.log(f"ref down {self.count}")


def thread(i):
    # references service with specific name
    myobj = Myobj(f"name{i % 2}")
    # only the first thread that gets here should start the service with that name
    myobj.start()
    # some_computation()
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0, 2))
    # only the last thread that gets here should stop the service with that name
    myobj.stop()


size = 6
with multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(size) as tp:
    tp.map(thread, range(size))
```

However, the counter is not unique:

```
140385706604224: name0: starting ab142d3c-2ebd-11ee-9d78-901b0e12b878
140385706604224: name0: ref up 1
140385698211520: name1: starting ab143264-2ebd-11ee-a67e-901b0e12b878
140385698211520: name1: ref up 1
140385689818816: name0: starting ab1435fc-2ebd-11ee-99f3-901b0e12b878
140385689818816: name0: ref up 1
140385681426112: name1: starting ab1439b2-2ebd-11ee-932c-901b0e12b878
140385681426112: name1: ref up 1
140385673033408: name0: starting ab143d36-2ebd-11ee-9959-901b0e12b878
140385673033408: name0: ref up 1
140385664640704: name1: starting ab1443f8-2ebd-11ee-a1b9-901b0e12b878
140385664640704: name1: ref up 1
140385673033408: name0: stopping ab143d36-2ebd-11ee-9959-901b0e12b878
140385673033408: name0: ref down 0
140385706604224: name0: stopping ab142d3c-2ebd-11ee-9d78-901b0e12b878
140385706604224: name0: ref down 0
140385689818816: name0: stopping ab1435fc-2ebd-11ee-99f3-901b0e12b878
140385689818816: name0: ref down 0
140385681426112: name1: stopping ab1439b2-2ebd-11ee-932c-901b0e12b878
140385681426112: name1: ref down 0
140385664640704: name1: stopping ab1443f8-2ebd-11ee-a1b9-901b0e12b878
140385664640704: name1: ref down 0
140385698211520: name1: stopping ab143264-2ebd-11ee-a67e-901b0e12b878
140385698211520: name1: ref down 0
```

Ideally, I should see the lines starting and stopping with `name0` and `name1` printed once, like the following means that service `name0` and service `name1` was started, and then stopped. The order between `name0` and `name1` services is not relevant. So only output like the following:

```
 140385706604224: name0: starting ab142d3c-2ebd-11ee-9d78-901b0e12b878
 140385698211520: name1: starting ab143264-2ebd-11ee-a67e-901b0e12b878
 140385681426112: name0: stopping ab142d3c-2ebd-11ee-9d78-901b0e12b878
 140385664640704: name1: stopping ab143264-2ebd-11ee-a67e-901b0e12b878
```

What can be a good design to implement such class that starts and stops unique named service with multiple threads once? Can this be implemented as a generic class?

Comment: I think the problem is just that your class variable counter is an immutable object, so (re)assigning it in an instance method only changes the value local to the instance. If you just make a custom object for the class variable counter, it would work how you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Just make your counter a mutable object and it should behave how you want.

Right now, your class variable `count` is an `int`, an immutable type. If this were a mutable type, then it would share its values across instances how you're expecting.

```py
class Foo:
    x = 0
    def incr(self):
        self.x += 1

a = Foo()
b = Foo()
a.incr()
print(Foo.x, a.x, b.x)  # change is not shared
```

But if you use a mutable object like `collections.Counter`, this works as you might expect:

```py
from collections import Counter
class Foo:
    x = Counter()
    def incr(self):
        self.x['x'] += 1
a = Foo()
b = Foo()
a.incr()
print(Foo.x, a.x, b.x)  # x reference is the same for all objects
```

Applying this to your scenario:

```
import multiprocessing.pool
import random
import threading
import time
import uuid
from collections import Counter

def log(args):
    print(f"{threading.get_ident()}: {args}")


class Myobj:
    lock = threading.Lock()
    counts = Counter()
    values = dict()

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name

    def log(self, args):
        log(f"{self.name}: {args}")

    @property
    def count(self):
        return self.counts[self.name]
        
    @count.setter
    def count(self, new_count):
        self.counts[self.name] = new_count
        
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.values[self.name]
        
    @value.setter
    def value(self, new_value):
        self.values[self.name] = new_value
        
    def start(self):
        with self.lock:
            self.count += 1
            if self.count == 1:
                self.value = uuid.uuid1()
                self.log(f"starting {self.value}")
            self.log(f"ref up {self.count}")

    def stop(self):
        with self.lock:
            self.count -= 1
            if self.count == 0:
                self.log(f"stopping {self.value}")
            self.log(f"ref down {self.count}")


def thread(i):
    # references service with specific name
    myobj = Myobj(f"name{i % 2}")
    # only the first thread that gets here should start the service with that name
    myobj.start()
    # some_computation()
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0, 2))
    # only the last thread that gets here should stop the service with that name
    myobj.stop()


size = 6
with multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(size) as tp:
    tp.map(thread, range(size))
```

```
6089797632: name0: starting 4bb3694c-2ec8-11ee-8745-9d96bc9d9be2
6089797632: name0: ref up 1
6091517952: name1: starting 4bb3bf28-2ec8-11ee-8745-9d96bc9d9be2
6091517952: name1: ref up 1
6092091392: name0: ref up 2
6093238272: name1: ref up 2
6094958592: name0: ref up 3
6095532032: name1: ref up 3
6091517952: name1: ref down 2
6094958592: name0: ref down 2
6095532032: name1: ref down 1
6089797632: name0: ref down 1
6093238272: name1: stopping 4bb3bf28-2ec8-11ee-8745-9d96bc9d9be2
6093238272: name1: ref down 0
6092091392: name0: stopping 4bb3694c-2ec8-11ee-8745-9d96bc9d9be2
6092091392: name0: ref down 0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! In the output, `name1` service was not started and not stopped.

Comment: Ah, I see @KamilCuk -- I seem to have misunderstood the full intent of what you're doing. Same principle though -- you could use a mutable object like a dictionary whose keys are service names and values are the count.

Comment: @KamilCuk I've updated the answer accordingly.